# Is there a possibility to have YAML pipeline definition for all branches in one branch in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have multiple system versions on different branches:

- dev/1.0
- dev/2.0
- dev/3.0
- and so on...

So far I implemented CI by creating a YAML pipeline definition file on every branch. All files contain the same logic. It's tedious to merge changes in pipeline definitions to all versions when it's needed. Is there a possibility to have a pipeline definition on a single branch that will trigger on every pull request to chosen versions (i.e. PR for dev/1.0 will trigger the pipeline)?

So far I know that it's impossible to configure a triggering pipeline after PR from the YAML definition for Azure Devops (it's only working with GitHub Actions - [Discussion about it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pr-triggers-in-yaml-should-be-supported-on-azure-d/385329)), but it can be configured in the branch policies.

But is it possible maybe to configure part of the logic in YAML and in Azure Devops Branch policies so that after PR to listed branches pipeline logic will be "connected" to a YAML file that will be only in one branch?

Comment: I am not sure I got your issue: do you basically want to centralize your build pipeline  so that a single modification to the yaml is automatically spread to all branches? If so maybe [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#use-other-repositories) can help you since you can define a build template in a different repository and then use it in all your branches

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same concerns with both Azure DevOps and GitHub Workflows, and the answer to both is to make use of **another** git repo to host your workflow templates, pipelines, jobs, scripts, etc.  Then you can reference from your actual source code git repo to the CI\CD git repo hosting the yaml workflow.  So now when you make a change in the CI\CD git workflow then ALL branches in your git code repo immediately get the changes.

For Azure DevOps, see this [exmaple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops&pivots=templates-includes#use-other-repositories).

For GitHub Workflow, see this [document](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).

Please be aware that your code git repo will still have a basic template/workflow with triggers, but they will call the CI\CD git repo to carry out the actual work.  I hope this helps.